# Hiding URL in view page source

Tags: javascript, html

I wanna hide a particular url in my html page from view page source.
This is my html page:

```
a href="http://.[myservername]/manifest.f4m"/> "
```

If I right click and view page source the url is visible, but I don't want the url(`http://.[myservername]/manifest.f4m`) to be visible on right click.
Is that possible to hide a url from view page source or the whole `<a>` tag can be removed from page source?

Comment: There's an old trick where you can encode the whole HTML code into a randomized javascript string.... I wouldn't recommend this tho.

Comment: What's the point in hiding the URL anyway? After clicking the link, it will be plainly visible in the browser's address bar.

Comment: my server name should not be visible.since the url contains my server name i wanna hide it.

Comment: why don't you want your server name to be visible? It will be visible in the browser address bar.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer : No.

You can't hide an information that will have to be read by the browser.

You can use code obfuscating in javascript but the address will still be reachable after deobfuscation or interpretation.

So no.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have noted; it is not possible to hide a URL - it would be possible to obfuscate it a little, but one analysing the script code in your page would be able to get to your URL nonetheless.

That could be of some use if you just would nto like passing users to go straight to an image or something, but it would be catastrohphic in any context were you really need security. - because the ones interested in profiting from you hidden resources would be the one investing time in bypassing your obfuscation barrier.

The closer you can get to what you want is not hidding the URL - is to generate server side a cryptographic token that would allow the giver resource to be fetched one single time from your server (afterwards, the token is inalidated).

Again, it can help in certain contexts, but you could not then prevent the client from saving the fetched reource to his local machinne.

Answer (score 0):

no you can't. unless you want to re-code your client's browser

Answer (score 0):

No, I do not think it is possible to hide the URL. The browser needs to know the URL, otherwise it is not able to load the image or build the clickable link or whatever. So the URL needs to be there.

What you can do is to obfuscate the URL. To make it readable to machines but not for humans. For example by using Base64-Encoding.